# Linkedin Profile Link

Tags: linkedin-api

Just curious (maybe this is an implementation detail so you may not know) but what are all these `_1*` chars are for in a LinkedIn link? When you start going to more profiles it gets longer and longer...

*E.g.*

```
&authType=name&authToken=FGH&goback=%2Efmp_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1&trk=pbmap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional information in the URL is used to track what pages you've visited, in what order, so LinkedIn can better structure the site in a way that gets people to the information they're looking for.